# AWS S3 FIle Containing Whitespace

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a lambda function within AWS which is triggered by an S3 upload event. When uploading a file containing whitespace to the S3 bucket I see

```
"AccessDenied: Access Denied",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:700:35)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
```

I am uploading a file hello world.csv

```
console.log('File path: ' + submission.s3.object.key);
```

gives the below:

File path: hello+world.csv

My lambda is using const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); to read the content of the event from the S3 bucket.

I have seen similar issues raised previously but they seem to have been resolved.

How can I reference the correct path to my file within my lambda?

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape them spaces

```js
var path = '/path/with spaces/in/them/'; 
var escapedPath = path.replace(/(\s)/, "\\ ");
```

on yow case it might look like this

```js
var path = submission.s3.object.key; 
var escapedPath = path.replace(/(\s)/, "\\ ");
console.log('File path: ' + espacedPath);
```